# How to use catbox for redis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, redis, node-redis

i am using this package  https://www.npmjs.com/package/catbox for operations in redis cache , i configured as per the documentation but i am getting this error

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Disconnected`

**My Code**

```
const Catbox = require('catbox');
const catBoxRedis = require('catbox-redis');
```

**My Gist**

https://gist.github.com/mariyappan88/14bf047484449708c61176211e694f80

Comment: So from your gist, I presume you have a local Redis cache running? FYI it's better to post all your code here in SO...

Comment: @James tht's a lot more code

Comment: I've read the gist, it's not really.

Comment: @James alternatively i used https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis without using catbox